# OneDrive Sync with SharePoint is showing the files in Read-Only mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning, onedrive-for-business, sync

We have a document library inside our online classic team site, and it has a custom content type which mimic the built-in Document content type:-

[image]

Also we have the following versioning settings:-

[image]

Now users are able to sync the SharePoint library with OneDrvie, but the synced files will be in Read-Only mode. can anyone advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.Check if there is column set as Required, if so, make all columns are not Required.

2.Check if the Draft Item Security is set to either Only users who can edit or Only users who can approve items in version settings of library, if so, change the settings to all users can edit/view.

If the issue persists, you could remove sync-blocking column settings to resolve this issue.

References about how to remove sync-blocking column settings:

[Libraries with specific columns or metadata](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but based on my test if i enable content approval and i set the "Draft Item Security" to "Any user who can read items",, the sync will be in read-only,, so seems regardless of the "Draft Item Security" setting ,, if we have content approval set to yes then the sync will be in read-only...

Comment: It means that after setting content approval to no, you can sync files normally. Thank you for the sharing.